# Grabbing page names for header.php

Tags: php, title

For my `header.php` file, I would like to grab the `<title>` via php and having trouble doing this. I know calling the constant would work, but that would mean I would need multiple files (which is bad practice). Any further help would be appreciated.

```
define("HOME", dirname(__DIR__)."index.php"); 
define("ABOUT", dirname(__DIR__)."../about/index.php"); 
define("WORK", dirname(__DIR__)."../work/index.php"); 
define("SERVICES", dirname(__DIR__)."../services/index.php"); 
define("CLIENTS", dirname(__DIR__)."../clients/index.php"); 
define("CONTACT", dirname(__DIR__)."../contact/index.php"); 

$page_titles = array (
    'home_page' => 'Home | Page',
    'about_page' => 'About | Page',
    'work_page' => 'Work | Page',
    'services_page' => 'Services | Page',
    'clients_page' => 'Clients | Page',
    'contact_page' => 'Contact | Page'
);

if (HOME == $page_titles[0]) {
    return $page_titles[0];
}

if (ABOUT == $page_titles[1]) {
    return $page_titles[1];
}

if (WORK == $page_titles[2]) {
    return $page_titles[2];
}

if (SERVICES == $page_titles[3]) {
    return $page_titles[3];
}

if (CLIENTS == $page_titles[4]) {
    return $page_titles[4];
}

if (CONTACT == $page_titles[5]) {
    return $page_titles[5];
}
```

Comment: 1) What have you tried and 2) What does the code you've posted pertain to?

Comment: I've tried echoing a constant, but I know that doesn't work if you want to use just one header.php file.

Comment: **1.** `var = comparison` is an **assignment**, not a comparison. You'll need at least two equals signs otherwise your statement will always evaluate to true. **2.** your constant's values will **never** equal the values of your `$page_titles` array - just look at `Home | Page` vs `.../index.php` - will they match?

Comment: Another thing to note, it looks to me like you're putting index.php files inside a bunch of folders to replicate the `yoururl.com/pagename` format. You should really just have them appropriately named files like `pagename.php` in your root folder, compare the filenames in this specific example instead, and use htaccess mod_rewrite to set up routes to those files.

Comment: Thanks, I can do that. But right now I'm focused on the page titles, then onto the nav.php files.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're trying to actually do.  There are quite a few things wrong with your code here.  It's difficult to know what to change without knowing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Well in my header.php I basically just want to be able to pull in the right title for the page. So if I go to the about/index.php page I want the About Title to show up. Using only one header.php for this.

Comment: This is in the functions.php file that is included in the header.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page should define its own title.  But, if you really want to do it this way, here's a possible solution:

**whatever_page_you_load.php:**

```
define("PAGE", "WHATEVERPAGE");

include("header.php");
```

**header.php:**

```
$page_names = array(
  "HOME" => "Home Page",
  "WHATEVERPAGE" => "Whatever Page's Name";
);

$title = "Default Title";

if(defined("PAGE") && !empty($page_names[PAGE])) {
  $title = $page_names[PAGE];
}

echo "<title>" . htmlentities($title) . "</title>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like this after I switch names of variables with their values:

```
if (dirname(__DIR__)."index.php" == 'Home | Page'){
    return 'Home | Page';
}
```

The condition in the statement `dirname(__DIR__)."index.php" == 'Home | Page'` will never evaluate to `true`.

One example of having a specific title for a specific page is to pass page name in URL and then display page name accordingly:

```
$titles = [
    'home' => 'Home title',
    'contact' => 'Contact title',
    // Other titles omitted    
];

$page = 'home';
if (array_key_exists('page', $_GET) && array_key_exists($_GET['page'], $titles)){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}

echo '<title>' . $titles[$page] . '</title>';
```

Comment: How would you propose I move forward with this? I know the current idea I have probably wouldn't work.